# java compare multiple values and find best match

Tags: java, oracle

I need to find best matched employee salary in the DB records as:

```
Name:   City:     State:

A       (null)    (null)

A       (null)    DEL

(null)  (null)    (null)

A        SAKET    DEL
```

Match order should be:

**1.** NAME = name, STATE = state, CITY = city

**2.** NAME = name, STATE = state , CITY = NULL

**3.** NAME = name, STATE = NULL, CITY = NULL

**4.** NAME = NULL, STATE = NULL, CITY = NULL

Means if in a row where all attributes matches – it should be selected, if we do not have that kind of data we should go to next best option like select state and city as NULL, etc.

My code as below, is giving me correct results but I need a more efficient way.

```
    private static BigDecimal getsalaryForBestMatch(ResultSet results, EmployeeRq request) throws Exception{
    BigDecimal salary = null;
    BigDecimal salaryWithState = null;
    BigDecimal salaryWithName = null;
    BigDecimal salaryWithNoMatch = null;
     while (results.next()) {

        String billerName = results.getString("EMP_NAME") != null ? results.getString("EMP_NAME").trim() : null;
        String city = results.getString("CITY") != null ? results.getString("CITY").trim() : null;
        String state = results.getString("STATE") != null ? results.getString("STATE").trim() : null;

        BigDecimal salaryRslt = null;

        if(results.getString("SALARY") != null){
            salaryRslt = BigDecimal.valueOf(results.getDouble("SALARY"));               
        }  
        if(billerName != null && !billerName.equals("") && billerName.equals(request.getBillPaymentsalaryCalculateInfo().getBillerName())){
            if(city != null && !city.equals("") && city.equals(request.getMsgRqHdr().getCity()) &&
                    state != null && !state.equals("") && state.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMsgRqHdr().getstate())){
                salary = salaryRslt;
                break;
            } else if((city == null || city.equals("")) && state != null && !state.equals("") &&
                    state.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMsgRqHdr().getState())){
                salaryWithState = salaryRslt;                   
            } else if((city == null || city.equals("")) && (state == null || state.equals(""))){
                salaryWithName = salaryRslt;                    
            }
        } else if((billerName == null || billerName.equals("")) && (city == null || city.equals("")) && 
                (state == null || state.equals(""))){
            salaryWithNoMatch = salaryRslt;             
        }
     }

     if(salary != null){
         return salary;
     } else if(salaryWithState != null){
         salary = salaryWithState;
     } else if(salaryWithName != null){
         salary = salaryWithName;
     } else if(salaryWithNoMatch != null){
         salary = salaryWithNoMatch;
     } 

     return salary;

}
```

**EDIT**: I dont want to use 3 extra variables: salaryWithState, salaryWithName,  salaryWithNoMatch.

Comment: This might be better off on Code Review

Comment: Use- StringUtils.isBlank(). It will check for Empty, Blank and NULL String in single shot. This will simplify your code at some level.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal or OP may create a static method to do so if he doesn't wanna use a Library Class.. but it's a good suggestion though

Comment: Thanks. Please check my Edit above: can I do away with the 3 extra variables: salaryWithState, salaryWithName, salaryWithNoMatch ?

Answer (score 0):

I want just to give the general idea how this can be implemented, so I haven't actually tested and checked if it will give you the right salary.

```
public BigDecimal getSalaryForBestMatch(ResultSet resultSet, PaymentSalaryInfo paymentSalaryInfo) {
    Map<String, Supplier<String>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("EMP_NAME", paymentSalaryInfo::getBillerName);
    m1.put("STATE", paymentSalaryInfo::getState);
    m1.put("CITY", paymentSalaryInfo::getCity);

    Map<String, Supplier<String>> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("STATE", paymentSalaryInfo::getState);
    m2.put("CITY", paymentSalaryInfo::getCity);

    Map<String, Supplier<String>> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    m3.put("CITY", paymentSalaryInfo::getCity);


    Optional<String> salary = Optional.empty();

    while(resultSet.next() && !salary.isPresent()) {
        salary = apply(m1, resultSet);
        //check salary and then apply(m2, resultSet) ....
    }

    return salary.isPresent() ? new BigDecimal(salary.get()) : null;
}


public Optional<String> apply(Map<String, Supplier<String>> filter, ResultSet resultSet) {
    boolean allMatch = filter.entrySet().stream().allMatch(entry -> {
        String value = resultSet.getString(entry.getKey());

        return value != null && value.equals(entry.getValue().get());
    });

    return allMatch ? Optional.of(resultSet.getString("salary")) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the same logic in a different way with using arrays. If your environment can afford to use arrays, you can use this code. But I have not tested the code.

```
 private static BigDecimal getsalaryForBestMatch(ResultSet results, EmployeeRq request) throws Exception{
    BigDecimal salary = null;
    int matchCount = 0;
    String rBillerName = request.getBillPaymentsalaryCalculateInfo().getBillerName();
    String rCity = request.getMsgRqHdr().getCity();
    String rState = request.getMsgRqHdr().getstate();

    String [] truthArray = new String[] {rBillerName, rCity, rState};

    while (results.next()) {
        String billerName = results.getString("EMP_NAME") != null ? results.getString("EMP_NAME").trim() : null;
        String city = results.getString("CITY") != null ? results.getString("CITY").trim() : null;
        String state = results.getString("STATE") != null ? results.getString("STATE").trim() : null;
        BigDecimal salaryRslt = results.getString("SALARY") != null ? BigDecimal.valueOf(results.getDouble("SALARY")): null;

        String [] testArray = new String[] {billerName, city, state};

        int localMatchCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
            if(testArray[i] != null && testArray[i].equals(truthArray[i]))
                localMatchCount++;
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(localMatchCount >= matchCount){
            matchCount = localMatchCount;
            salary = salaryRslt;
        }
    }
    return salary;
}
```